# After maven installation exception UnsupportedClassVersionError recieved

Tags: java, maven

After finishing Maven installation I tried to execute command `mvn -version` and I get :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/ma
    ven/cli/MavenCli : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
......
```

I''m using `jdk1.6` and `maven-3.3.3`. Also I created variables `M2_HOME` and write it in Path variable. Can problem be with an old verion of jdk?

Comment: JRE\JDK version  mismatch. you have to use 1.7 and above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can problem be with an old verion of jdk?

Yes, there is a problem.  From the [Maven installation notes](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi):

> Maven 3.3 requires JDK 1.7 or above, Maven 3.2 requires JDK 1.6 or above, while Maven 3.0/3.1 requires JDK 1.5 or above (this is to execute Maven - it still allows you to build against 1.3 and prior JDK's: see our Guide to Using Toolchains)

You need to upgrade your JDK to 7 or higher, or downgrade Maven to the 3.2 version.

After you have installed JDK 7 or 8, please remember to update your `JAVA_HOME` PATH variable to point to the new location.